# populate values from data base in select box in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am new in zend framework. I want to populate company name and company id from database to select box. in zend

example as we do it PHP

```
<option value="<?php echo id ?>" > <?php echo $comapnyName ?>
```

this is my form

```
$this->addElement('select', 'companyName', array(           
    'required'   => true,
    'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
    'style'    => array('width:103px'),
    'decorators'=> array(
        'ViewHelper','Errors'
    )
));
```

help me

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name is `multiOptions` and requires an array with the value=>companyName pairs for your option elements.

So either add it to your statement above when you create the element or later with `$element->setMultiOptions($options)`

Comment: tell me the code how to get companyName values from databases or where i write my sql query for retrieving the data base values and populate in the list box

Comment: @Delta that is an entirely different topic and you must open a new question. from your original question we have to assume you already know that.